# how to on/off toggle button based on coming values from db [ ionic ]

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

i have one screen.in that i have one toggle button. And from database value 1 0r 2 will come. if 1 i have to swift on the toggle button or else i have to switch off.

how can i do this :

my code :

```
<label class="item item-input " style="height: 50px;"><span class="input-label"><font style="color:#696969; padding-top: 0px;">Claim</font></span>
                    <ion-toggle toggle-class="toggle-calm" class="tog" ng-model="data.toggle"></ion-toggle>
      </label>
```

**my controller that i tried :**

```
$scope.data = {}  
 var toggle_value;
  var toggleStatus = $scope.data.toggle 
if ($scope.singleDetail.ExpClaimReimb == 1) {

toggleStatus == true;


}
else {

  toggleStatus == false;

}
```

From db the value will come here only :

**`$scope.singleDetail.ExpClaimReimb`**

please help me out. how can i do this ??

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're probably using an equality check (==) where you should be using assignment (=).

```
toggleStatus = true; //this, instead of
toggleStatus == true;
```